# Use Vaadin badge in lit element

Tags: vaadin, web-component, lit

I'm trying to use [vaadin badges](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/components/badge) in lit element.

The documentation is mentioning to "To use these classes in your application, enable them in your theme’s theme.json" but I don't have such a file so it is really confusing to me. Most of the documentation focuses on Java so I am guessing this is where the confusion comes from. So far I have only installed some components via NPM.

I tried to create a `frontend/themes/common-theme/theme.json` file anyways, but without success so far.

Here is how my element looks like at the moment :

```
import {LitElement, html} from 'lit';

import '@vaadin/vertical-layout';
import '@vaadin/horizontal-layout';

import '@vaadin/vaadin-lumo-styles/badge.js';

export class PaymentLink extends LitElement {
    static properties = {
        version: {},
        link : { Object}
    };

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    render() {
        return html`
            <vaadin-horizontal-layout>
                <a href="${this.link.url}">${this.link.id}</a>
                <span theme="badge">Pending</span>
            </vaadin-horizontal-layout>
    `;
    }

}
customElements.define('payment-link', PaymentLink);
```

Could someone please show me the light? Here is a stackblitz example : https://stackblitz.com/edit/lit-element-jjzdpa?file=src/index.js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `@vaadin/vaadin-lumo-styles/badge.js` module only exports the styles, just importing it will not automatically create a style tag with the respective CSS. With Vaadin Flow or Hilla applications that can done automatically by configuring said theme JSON file.

If you want to use badge standalone in a Lit app, the best approach is probably to add the badge styles to the styles of your root / application Lit component:

```js
import { badge } from '@vaadin/vaadin-lumo-styles/badge.js';

class MyLitApp extends LitElement {
  static get styles() {
    return [badge, /* ...other app styles */]
  }
}
```

Note that if one of your components using badge uses a shadow root, then you need to add the badge styles to that component in the same manner.

Comment: Yes, here is an example of Badge as lit based component https://github.com/TatuLund/badge/blob/v23/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/frontend/badge.ts, can be found also via Directory https://vaadin.com/directory/component/badge

Comment: Can confirm it works, thanks!